# Live TCP Connection constraints

Tags: tcp, vb6, winsock

I am working in a legacy VB6 project that involves TCP Communication using sockets.

Application requires long lived socket connections but i doubt to how much extent it is possible.
Application runs in windows OS.
If after a socket connection in established and some data is exchanged at regular intervals say 30 sec,
will the connection lives forever or is there any constraints from OS or TCP stack or network provider?

Comment: "requires long lived socket", no, it is always a bad idea because TCP sockets necessitate to have allocated ressources at different places along the path. So, to be fair you should not use a connection for very long time. Don't overcome any timeout... If you use dummy packets to get the connection alive, then a reconnection may do the exact same trick for you, isn't it?

Comment: Dear @ Jean-Baptiste Yunès, Our application listens for connections from embedded devices which have attached network modem. Application need to get data from devices at scheduled intervals. If we close connection after a session,we need to wait for connection request from device in next interval.

Comment: As long as you are able to cope with disconnections (accepting new connections from the same device and resuming what you were doing) you should be fine. Just view the continuous connections as an optimization. But you can’t assume the connection must stay up. And if you only get data every 30 seconds or so, you’re not really gaining much. The TCP protocol will not break the connection on you, but intervening network devices might.

Answer (score 1):

There is no technical limitation against having a TCP socket connected for months on end.

Skype will have a 24/7 TCP session established to a server as long as it's running.

The idea of TCP is that you:

- <kbd>syn</kbd>→
- ← <kbd>syn</kbd><kbd>ack</kbd>
- <kbd>ack</kbd>→

And now your connection is established. Barring some technical issue (rebooted machines), that TCP connection will stay up forever. Yes there may be various edge firewalls that have to maintain stateful information about that TCP/IPv6 (or TCP/IPv4) connection - but that is the firewall's problem.

Their job is to route traffic. If they can't handle *n* open connections: then they need to be redesigned.